# Can an RPG Leveling System be simulated on MS Excel?

Tags: rpg, progression

I'm interested in seeing quickly if my leveling system still makes sense at level 60.  Is there a quick way to do this on Excel?

Comment: Why would it not be possible? Just use the same equation.

Comment: It's hard to tell what kind of answer you are searching for. It whould help when you would discribe what problems did you encountered when you tried to create an Excel spreadsheet to simulate your game system.

Comment: it's a really easy thing to do with formulas. Example: "=(address of box above) * 1.1"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. This is a common way to tweak and evaluate these formulas. Enter the formula in one cell, with the inputs to the formula referencing other cells. Fill in the data to the "input" cells to see what kind of output you get.

Comment: As an aside, in the future you may just want to try these simple types of things out before posting a question about them. You asked this question about an hour ago, it takes 5 minutes to try for yourself.